# Basic problems dealing with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm having problems getting my head around Fragments, but before I get to more advanced issues (like what is the recommended approach regarding layout changes) I already fail at a basic level.

Below I have the example code of my project in which I want to accomplish **two things**:

- Add and **remove** fragments
- Have the Views/ViewGroups/Fragments adjust their sizes when stuff is being added/removed (I figure that would be useful once I get to the point where I worry about adjusting the layout for the different screen modes), like so:

  ```
  ------------------
  | -------------- |
  | |            | |
  | |            | |
  | |            | |
  | | ViewGroup1 | |
  | |            | |
  | |            | |
  | |            | |
  | |            | |
  | -------------- |
  ------------------

         ==>  (by pressing a button, layout, event, ...)

  ------------------
  | -------------- |
  | |            | |
  | | ViewGroup1 | |
  | |            | |
  | -------------- |
  | -------------- |
  | |            | |
  | | ViewGroup2 | |
  | |            | |
  | -------------- |
  ------------------
  ```

Right now I fail at both:

- When I try to remove a fragment the app crashes with a NullPointerException (I assume I'm not getting the fragment I want to remove?).
- The only way I got the adding of fragments to work was if I give them a specific height (like 50dp in my example), but the 0dp/weight=1 approach for a LinearLayout resulted in the first element taking up the whole screen and adding a 2nd element not showing up (I assume it is covered by the first element?). I had no success whatsoever in my feeble attempts to get this to work (FrameLayouts, RelativeLayout, etc.).

Here is my example code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/iRootLinearLayoutContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iMainButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Add fragment..." 
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button fragmentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iMainButton);

    fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(fragmentButton.getText().equals("Add fragment..."))
            {
                Log.d("MainActivity.java: ", "Clicking Button and hopefully adding fragment.");
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.iRootLinearLayoutContainer, new TestFragment());
                ft.commit();
                fragmentButton.setText("Remove fragment...");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("MainActivity.java: ", "Clicking Button and hopefully removing fragment.");
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.iTestFragment);
                ft.remove(frag);
                ft.commit();
                fragmentButton.setText("Add fragment...");                  
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**ltestfragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/iTestFragment"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="This is my test fragment." 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.ltestfragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

As per request here the error log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
>   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
>   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
> ```

Comment: Posting error messages from logcat will get you better answers.

Comment: Done, even though that is only half the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.iTestFragment)` to find a fragment by id. But I don't see where you set that id for that fragment in first place.

`R.id.iTestFragment` is id of a LinearLayout object, not of its container, Fragment object.

A Fragment must have an id if its embedded in a layout with the `<fragment>` tag. For finding fragments from code, set a "tag" string when you add them.

For example:

> ft.add(R.id.iRootLinearLayoutContainer, new TestFragment(),"uniqueTag");

and later, to find it:

> Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("UniqueTag");

Comment: Awesome! That works. Though I don't understand where exactly I would set that id in this case (does it only work when using a "fragment" as container?.
Now all I need for now is to be able to add those fragments while being able to rearrange the layout.

Comment: @Markstar You set an id when you do something like `<fragment name="MyFragment" id="@+id/my_fragment" />` in an xml layout.

Comment: I'm sorry.
For the life of me I can't get the example above to work with using id, let alone so that it actually does what I want and re-sizes the rest of the screen when adding/removing the fragment. 
I would greatly appreciate if you could show me which lines you would change so that it works with id. When I use findFragmentById, it does return something (=> not null), but the app crashes whenever I want to do something with it.